# How do I numerically compare the Dymos solution to the simulated solution?

Tags: openmdao

I want to conduct a convergence study for my Dymos optimization results where I vary the number of nodes and compare the simulated solution to the optimization solution. From what I understand, Dymos fits polynomials to the system dynamics to represent the timeseries solution. What is the best way to compare the polynomial trajectory of the optimization solution to the trajectory of the simulated solution? I specifically want to evaluate the difference between the two trajectories away from the collocation/control nodes... to show that the polynomial fitting actually represents the simulated solution. How would I access the polynomial fitting data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some of the testing we have an [assert_timeseries_near_equal](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/blob/bb1cadc80a2cc1c2cdf2d922c8b69ea011d8bead/dymos/utils/testing_utils.py#L126) function that treats the more dense time series as the truth and tests that the less dense timeseries (usually the discrete solution) is reasonably close to it.

We're actually working on this method a bit more explicit right now so it's a little easier for users to apply in general cases, such as comparing discrete solutions from two different cases.

In general, there's a few different ways you can test your explicit results against an explicit integration.  You *could* just verify that the final states of the two solutions are reasonably close.  Since the error tends to increase over the course of the trajectory this is often good enough for a quick check. The downside of this approach is that it doesn't test that both solutions took the same path to the final condition.

To test the solution away from the nodes I'd recommend the following:  [Add a second timeseries output](https://openmdao.github.io/dymos/features/phases/timeseries.html#interpolated-timeseries-outputs) to the relevant phase that contains more segments or higher order segments.  This timeseries will have more nodes.  Dymos will interpolate from the solution's collocation grid onto this more dense timeseries output grid.  Comparing this against the explicit simulation should still match exactly in terms of times, controls, and parameters, you'll better capture the interpolating state polynomials vs the explicitly simulated results.

There are other statistical methods out there for comparing timeseries that you can bring to bear, but visualizing the explicit trajectory plus some error bound as a "tube" into which we want to fit the discrete solution is usually how I handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think the 'assert timeseries' or 'adding a second timeseries output' would do the trick for me. They both seem fairly straightforward to implement, so thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: I wanted to clarify so I understand precisely what Dymos is doing. When a second timeseries output is added, is it evaluating the polynomial values and rates at the new time gridding? I want to verify that the added timeseries directly evaluates the polynomial information and not just linearly interpolating the optimization solution (for example). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Correct, it is NOT linear interpolation.  The states/controls of the phase are prescribed at nodes on the transcriptions grid, for example, 10 5th order segments.  To get more points in the secondary timeseries output we could use, for instance, 10 7th order segments.  If we plotted those outputs they would still look like 5th order polynomials, the interpolation is just providing a more dense representation of the original 5th order solution.